# Что значит обратный апостроф в c#?

Tags: c#, экранирование

В одном из примеров встретил такой код:

```
foreach (var blkName in blkNames)
{
tvl.Add (blkName.StartsWith("*") ? "`" + blkName : blkName)
}
```

Если имя объекта начинается с символа "*", то добавить обратный апостроф. Что этот апостроф в c# значит?

Comment: Эм. Ничего. Это как бы просто строка. А что означает `"k"` в `С#`? Это строковое представление буквы `k`

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях тебе уже ответ дали ну я сделаю формальней так сказать. 
Да, действительно, это строковое представление символа ' и нечего более, просто нужно было автору кода найти строки с началом в виде * и приписать к началу ещё и

> обратный апостроф

Так что там вместо этого символа мог быть любой другой и от этого основная суть данного блока кода не изменилась.